# Parsing a user-input value

Tags: javascript

I would like to allow a user to enter some input, and the program to parse that as a js type, if it can. For example, in what the user types into the text input is:

- Hello -> "Hello" (string)
- 2.13 -> 2.13 (number)
- true -> true (bool)

Would the following accomplish this in a very basic fashion, ignoring nested objects and such?

```js
function parseValueFromText(text) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch(e) {
        if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
            return text;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
let a=parseValueFromText('hello'),
    b=parseValueFromText(123);
console.log(a, typeof a);
console.log(b, typeof b);
```

Comment: The problem is always in the edge cases… What if I want to enter `"hello"`, *with quotes*? Or exactly the string  `3.14`, not a float…?

Comment: If anything that isn't valid JSON should be treated as a string, then it will work.

Comment: @deceze: It's not wonderful, but ` "\"hello\""` and `"\"3.14\""` would work for those cases.

Comment: So many questions.   I presume, it would start as a string, and then *if* it is a Number, make it a number, (use Number.parseFloat) and *if* it is a boolean, make it a boolean, right?  How relaxed about Booleans would you like to be?  `true` `True` `TRUE` `YES`, etc.  Do you want to handle other types like BigInt?  Date?  Null?  Symbol?  Is there a way for me to enter the **string** `42`?  Do you want it to remove quotes if it finds them?  Do you want to permit escape sequences?

Comment: @Wyck well I was thinking of using `eval(...)` to handle some of that, but it seems so strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Wyck: Agreed.  There are possibilities, but there are so many questions.

Comment: @Scott Do you want to explain this to your user? Should they be aware…?

Comment: @deceze: I don't think this is a great idea, but it's at least intriguing.  Note that the escaped quotes in my examples are only to wrap things up for a demo.  Presumably in the real world, the input would *already* start as a string (from a text box, a web service, somewhere) and the user would only enter `"hello"` and `"3.14"`.

Comment: @Scott Well, no, if I, as a user, want to enter the text  `"hello"`, *including quotes*, I'd have to *know* that the app will interpret my input as JSON and that I need to enter `"\"hello\""` in order to get `"hello"`. — And again, is that something the user should be aware of, and do you want to explain it to them, or is it a negligible problem if I enter `"hello"` and the app ends up using `hello`?

Comment: @deceze: Sorry, brain fart, I guess.  I have no idea how big a deal that is to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is pretty close, but if JSON.parse results in a string then you likely want the original string, not the result of the parse.

Also, I think that any exception should result in the original string.

```js
function parseValueFromText(text) {
  try {
    const result = JSON.parse(text);
    if (typeof result !== 'string') return result;
  } catch {}
  return text;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. By the way, what does doing a bare `catch {}` do?

Comment: @David542 It just falls through to the `return text` below.  You can't have a `try` without a `catch` or `finally`.   Cleaner than `return text; } catch { return text; }`

Comment: I see. so would replacing `catch {}` with `finally {}` do the same thing?

Comment: "*you likely want the original string, not the result of the parse.*" - do you really? Getting the result of the parse allows me to enter `"42"` and get `42` as a string, which I could not achieve otherwise.

Comment: @David542 "*would replacing `catch {}` with `finally {}` do the same thing?*" - no, since that wouldn't handle the exception. It would run the (empty) `finally` block and then rethrow the exception, never reaching `return text`.